# 2D sprite 360 degrees rotation according to the mouse

Tags: c#, 2d, rotation, mouse

I am trying to make my top down character rotate according to degrees between its position and the mouse. I'm using this code:

```
float xDiff = mouseState.X - (graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2);
            float yDiff = mouseState.Y - (graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2);

float angle = (float)(Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff)) * 180 / Math.PI);
```

But it's not working. At the place where I should get somewhere about 0 degrees - I get about -75.

Comment: Normalise ( xDiff, yDiff ) before you convert to degrees.

Comment: Can you tell me the code for it? I can't find function like that in  c#.

Comment: @user54580 What are the values of `xDiff`,  `yDiff` and `angle` when it gives the wrong result?

Comment: @KellyThomas While the angle is -90, the xDiff == -2 and yDiff == -145. Something's not right at all here...

Comment: I'm really sorry I know this isn't a long and clear answer but I can't comment here. Have you read this ? maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174767/how-do-you-rotate-a-sprite-based-on-mouse-position

Comment: That's basically the same what I tried to do in my example above.

Comment: Hum so, I don't know what it can be... Because it's simple trigonometry math...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you look at a circle with the angles marked you will see that `270 degrees` corresponds with `(0,-1)` i.e. straight down.

By convention degrees are marked as acceding in a counter-clockwise direction. They do however form a loop and as such `270 degrees` (purple arrow) can also be expressed as `-90 degrees` (orange arrow) i.e. a quarter turn in the opposite direction.

The coordinates that you provided `(-2, -145)` correspond with both `269.21` and `-90.79 degrees` depending on how you choose to express this angle..

The documentation for [`Atan2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for .Net 4.5 states that it will return value is the range `-π <= θ <= π`, after converting to degrees this is `-180 <= θ <= 180`.

To further explain the expected results here is a table with the results of the following formula with the corresponding values of `x` and `y`.

```
angle = Math.Atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI;

         x    -1       0       1
   y   +------------------------
   1   |     135      90      45
   0   |     180       0       0
  -1   |    -135     -90     -45
```

If you prefer to have your angles expressed in the range `0 <= θ <= 360` they are easy to convert:

```
while (angle > 360) {
    angle -= 360;
}
while (angle < 0) {
    angle += 360;
}
```

Comment: It almost works as it should. One problem that I have is that instead of 270 degrees I get - 90 and instead of 90 I get - 270. The angle is rotated for some reasons... Any ideas?

Comment: Is your order of operations backwards vs your x and y?

Comment: Shroeder, I tried to change the order, and it worked, but now I noticed that instead of 0 I get - 180 and instead of 180 I get - 0. How can I fix that?

Comment: @user54580 Please see edit clarifying what to expect from .net 4.5 implementation of `Atan2()`. It is unusual that you are receiving `-270`.  What implementation of the math libraries  are you using? .Net or Mono? Which version?  Despite appearing to be out of range `-270` is likely "correct" and can be translated to your desired range using code similar to the snippet above.

Comment: Kelly Thomas, I use .Net 4.0. I can't use a newer version. I did as Shroeder told me and I reordered my operations from previous to float xDiff = (graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2) - mouseState.X;
            float yDiff = (graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2) - mouseState.Y; And now it works, just instead of 0 now I get 180 degrees. Degrees work vertically, but not horizontally.

Comment: Do you want the angle from the screen center to the mouse? or from the mouse to the screen center? These are the changes you are making with this change to the formula.

Comment: I am not completely sure which one I need. Because I want to get mouse angle according to character's position and to set character's facing direction (8 directions).

Comment: In that case you want the angle of 'mousePosition - characterPosition'.

Comment: Yeah, but that would be the same problem. I just assume that the center of the screen now is my character. Or am I wrong?